# Runtime Warning overflow encountered in ubyte_scalars

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, image-recognition

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def threshold(imageArray):
    balanceAr = []
    newAr = imageArray
    for eachRow in imageArray:
        for eachPix in eachRow:
            avgNum = reduce(lambda x, y: x + y, eachPix[:3]) / len(eachPix[:3])
            balanceAr.append(avgNum)
    balance = reduce(lambda x, y: x + y, balanceAr) / len(balanceAr)
    for eachRow in newAr:
        for eachPix in eachRow:
            if reduce(lambda x, y: x + y, eachPix[:3]) / len(eachPix[:3]) > balance:
                eachPix[0] = 255
                eachPix[1] = 255
                eachPix[2] = 255
                eachPix[3] = 255
            else:
                eachPix[0] = 0
                eachPix[1] = 0
                eachPix[2] = 0
                eachPix[3] = 255
    return newAr




i = Image.open('images/numbers/0.1.png')
iar = np.asarray(i)
3iar = threshold(iar)

i2 = Image.open('images/numbers/y0.4.png')
iar2 = np.asarray(i2)
#iar2 = threshold(iar2)

i3 = Image.open('images/numbers/y0.5.png')
iar3 = np.asarray(i3)
#iar3 = threshold(iar3)

i4 = Image.open('images/sentdex.png') 
iar4 = np.asarray(i4)
#iar4 = threshold(iar4)

threshold(iar3)
fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = plt.subplot2grid((8,6), (0,0), rowspan = 4, colspan = 3)
ax2 = plt.subplot2grid((8,6), (4,0), rowspan = 4, colspan = 3)
ax3 = plt.subplot2grid((8,6), (0,3), rowspan = 4, colspan = 3)
ax4 = plt.subplot2grid((8,6), (4,3), rowspan = 4, colspan = 3)

ax1.imshow(iar)
ax2.imshow(iar2)
ax3.imshow(iar3)
ax4.imshow(iar4)

plt.show()
```

The error I'm getting:

```
Warning (from warnings module):
  File "C:\WinPython-32bit-2.7.9.5\python-2.7.9\Lib\idlelib\MuditPracticals\Image_Recognition\imagerec.py", line 11
    avgNum = reduce(lambda x, y: x + y, eachPix[:3]) / len(eachPix[:3])
RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in ubyte_scalars

Warning (from warnings module):
  File "C:\WinPython-32bit-2.7.9.5\python-2.7.9\Lib\idlelib\MuditPracticals\Image_Recognition\imagerec.py", line 16
    if reduce(lambda x, y: x + y, eachPix[:3]) / len(eachPix[:3]) > balance:
RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in ubyte_scalars

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\WinPython-32bit-2.7.9.5\python-2.7.9\Lib\idlelib\MuditPracticals\Image_Recognition\imagerec.py", line 47, in <module>
    threshold(iar3)
  File "C:\WinPython-32bit-2.7.9.5\python-2.7.9\Lib\idlelib\MuditPracticals\Image_Recognition\imagerec.py", line 17, in threshold
    eachPix[0] = 255
ValueError: assignment destination is read-only
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### Regarding the Overflow RuntimeWarnings:

---

You shouldn't worry about these, what they are essentially telling you is that the range for the `uint_8` (unsigned integer) `type` [defined by `numpy`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.types.html) and generally used for image files, has simply exceeded its acceptable range.

From the link supplied, `uint_8` types have a range of:

> Unsigned integer (0 to 255)

`numpy` just issues the warning to *inform* you of the overflow. Thankfully, it will automatically adjust the result into a value of acceptable range.

For example:

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np

img = Image.open("/path/to/image.png")
img_array = np.asarray(img) # array values are of type uint_8 (!)

print img_array[0][0] # prints [ 12,  21,  56, 255] 

uint8_1 = img_array[0][0][3] # = 255
uint8_2 = img_array[0][0][2] # = 56

uint8_3 = uint8_1 + uint8_2 

# When executed raises a RuntimeWarning of overflow ubyte_scalars
# But! The result 'rolls over' to the acceptable range. So,
print uint8_3  # prints 55
```

---

#### Regarding the actual Error:

---

Your ***error*** `ValueError: assignment destination is read-only` is actually raised when *assigning* values to your `numpy` array `newAr`.
It's informative, what it tells you is that the array is `read only`; the contents are *read only*: you can ***access*** them but ***cannot modify*** them.

So an action like this:

```
# using img_array from previous snippet.
img_array[0][0][0] = 200
```

Will raise a `ValueError`.

Thankfully, this is easily bypassed by setting a flag parameter for the array:

```
# using img_array from the previous snippet
# make it writeable 
img_array.setflags(write=True)

# Values of img_array[0][0] are, as before: [ 12,  21,  56, 255]
# changing the values for your array is possible now!
img_array[0][0][0] = 200

print img_array[0][0] # prints [ 200,  21,  56, 255]
```

---

#### Suppressing Overflow RuntimeWarnings:

---

**Final note**: You could always [suppress/ignore these warnings](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.seterr.html), even though this is generally not the best idea. (A couple of warnings in the console are annoying but they give you a clearer view of things)

To do this, just add the following after importing numpy:

```
import numpy as np
np.seterr(over='ignore')
```

Answer (score 0):

i1=Image.open('images/numbers/0.1.png')
iar1=np.array(i1)

rather than asarray methode use array

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing y:x+y with y:int(x)+int(y)